# Update UniqueConstrains on a JPA table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a table defined as follow:

```
@Entity
@Table(
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"reward_id", "transaction_id"})}
)
public class ShipmentItem extends Model {
    ...
}
```

I want to change the unique constraint to make it more relaxed:

```
@Entity
@Table(
        uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"reward_id", "transaction_id", "sku"})}
)
public class ShipmentItem extends Model {
    ...
}
```

The updated code compiles, but JPA doesn't change the table schema. Is there a configuration setting I need to use?

If JPA cannot do this, what's the systematic approach to this problem? I can write migration, however, JPA generates the name for the constraint automatically, so it's not obvious how to drop the old constraint.

Not sure if it matters, but I am using hibernate and mysql.

Comment: You could not rely on JPA creating the tables for you and use a solution like [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) where you will make all the changes yourself.

Comment: I concur with Blazej. In addition if you are using a database like PostgreSQL you can create the constraint DEFERRABLE which will solve allow you to update constraints but the DB will not perform the referential check until the end of the transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using Hibernate, there is a property for automatically updating your schema: **hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto** with the value **update**

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html

(But be aware that it is not recommended to use it on Production)

Comment: Interestingly, I have 'hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto' set to 'update' for both development and production and it still didn't update the constraint.